# In C, how do I allocate space for my struct?

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I built a function that I'm trying to use to dynamically allocate memory for my struct like so.  Just can't seem to get it to work

```
typedef struct My_Struct
{
    char **array
}MyStruct

MyStruct * createMyStruct(int length)
{
     MyStruct->array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (length + 1));   
}

int main(void)
{
     MyStruct *new1 = createMyStruct(10);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `MyStruct->array`. `MyStruct` is a type name, not a variable name.

Comment: You don't "allocate your struct", but you can allocate instances of your struct.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple as allocating `sizeof(MyStruct)` and casting to MyStruct ptr:

```
MyStruct * createMyStruct(int length)
{
     MyStruct* s = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
     s->array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (length + 1));   
     return s;
}
```

By the way, usually a struct doesn't have any pointers in it, but only arrays with fixed sizes or at least a `char*[]` instead of a `char*` since structs usually have a fixed size to be easier allocable.
If you use my above code don't forget to allocate the `char*`s the `char**` refers too since the malloc in my code only allocates the pointers and not the strings itselfes

Comment: `(MyStruct*)` and `(char**)` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could not use `MyStruct` type to initialize its fields, since they are not static. You have to create struct instance first, initialize it and then - return from your method.

```
MyStruct * createMyStruct(int length)
{
    MyStruct* pResult = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)); 
    pResult->array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (length + 1));
    return(pResult);   
}
```

Do not forget to free memory after you finish to use it.

PS:
This code is also strange:

```
pResult->array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (length + 1));
```

If you are trying to initialize array of strings of the same length, it is incorrect. You will get an array of `length+1`, containing uninitialized pointers. If you are simply allocating an array to use its later - then incrementing `length` is possibly wrong.

Comment: This probably should become a sparsed  array of "strings" with the pointer-array being `NULL` terminated (like `argv` in `main()`), so the +1 element would be for the sentinel.

Comment: May be, but that is unclear from the question. So I thought, that it is better to point out)

Comment: It also would be important to do error checking on the calls to `malloc()`.